# Prestodb + Python: Using a List as Query Argument

Tags: python, presto

I'm trying to use prestodb in Python and pass a list of numbers as an argument in a query and it's giving this error:

```
PrestoUserError: PrestoUserError(type=USER_ERROR, name=TYPE_MISMATCH, message="line 208:33: IN value and list items must be the same type: bigint", query_id=20211122_175131_24052_rruhu)
```

The code is similar to this:

```
import prestodb 
from prestodb import dbapi 
import os 

conn=prestodb.dbapi.connect(
    host=os.environ['aa'],
    port=os.environ['bb'],
    user=os.environ['cc'],
    password=os.environ['dd'],
    catalog='hive'
)

date_start = '2021-10-10'
date_end = '2021-10-15'
list_id = (1,2,3,4)

sql = '''
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   table
WHERE
   DATE BETWEEN '{date_start}'
   AND '{date_end}'
   AND ID in ({list_id})
   '''.format(date_start=date_start,date_end=date_end,list_id=list_id)

   cur = conn.cursor()

   cur.execute(sql)
   query_result = cur.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

`format` will not join the `list_id` correctly. Try combining ids into comma separated strings with `','.join(map(str, list_id))`:

```py
sql = '''
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   table
WHERE
   DATE BETWEEN '{date_start}'
   AND '{date_end}'
   AND ID in ({list_id})
   '''.format(date_start=date_start,date_end=date_end,list_id=','.join(map(str, list_id)))
```

**UPD**

Or, as suggested by [@Tomerikoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6045800/tomerikoo) - just `str(list_id)` and remove extra parenthesis from the format:

```py
sql = '''
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   table
WHERE
   DATE BETWEEN '{date_start}'
   AND '{date_end}'
   AND ID in {list_id}
   '''.format(date_start=date_start,date_end=date_end,list_id=str(list_id))
```